# Methods to correct for lookahead bias

Tags: r

**This is not a regex problem**.
I am trying to correct for lookahead bias in data, basically to move the values up by 1. This is what I came up with. Does anyone have a better/faster/ built-in method to do this?

```
d<-c(1,2,3,4)

#correct for lookahead bias, move values up by 1
e<-d[-c(1)]
length(e)<-length(d)
cbind(d,e)

> cbind(d,e)
     d  e
[1,] 1  2
[2,] 2  3
[3,] 3  4
[4,] 4 NA
```

Comment: Nice! Something like that is exactly what I was looking for.... I just couldnt find anything that wasnt regex related when I searched for "lookahead"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways I could think of to do this. Both are fairly concise one liners:

#### `base`

```
cbind(d, c(d[-1], NA))
```

#### `data.table`

```
rev(data.table::shift(rev(d), 1))
```

If we want to write it as a function, we can do that too. Note that this function does not attempt to error handle anything.

```
shift_up <- function(x, n = 1) c(x[-(1:n)], rep(NA, n))
```

Which is *[very useful](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091004202407AAmCea2)* for fans of the comic series *Batman*:

```
d <- 1:16
shift_up(d, 16)
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA #BATMAN!
```

Comment: Or `data.table::shift(d, 1, type="lead")`